# error catching in AUCTeX

Tags: errors, emacs, auctex

When working with AUCTeX, I experience an unexpected behavior regarding error catching. In particular, when I hit `C-c C-c`, and there are errors, then **C-c `** does two things:

1. Splits the window and opens a new tab.
2. In the lower (new) part an error message is displayed and in the new tab's title is `TeX Live 2011` and it is empty.

If I close the empty tab, and switch back to the `.tex` file, the cursor doesn't jump to the (vicinity) of the error. I find it hard to believe that this is the expected behavior. Is there a way to customize this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, it sometimes happen when the error is actually located in another file.

And this is an excerpt from the "Bugs" section of the AUCTeX manual, which might be relevant to your question:

> - **C-c `** should always stay in the current window, also when it finds a new file.

Answer (score 1):

To add to mbork's answer. Compare the following two small examples:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmatg}
\begin{document}
 stuff
\end{document}
```

This gives the "blank `` C-c ` ``  error"

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
 stuff
 \begin{aligm}
   xyz
 \end{aligm}
\end{document}
```

This doesn't.

If the problem can be traced to a line in the file, then it works, if it can't it doesn't. Why it can't trace where a missing package is loaded, I don't know. But the line number doesn't appear in the log file either...

In cases where `` C-c ` `` fails,
you have to go look at the log file itself (`C-c C-l`).

Comment: As a matter of fact, in both examples, the **C-c`** worked nicely... (PS, how do you typeset "C-c `" ?)

Comment: @Dror `<code>` tags. html works as well as markdown. Sometimes, you need it... I don't know why <code>C-c `</code> didn't work for me in the package example then... weird.

Comment: `<code>` tags don't work in comments, however. Well, now you know how I wrote it in the post!

Comment: @Seamus: maybe this has something to do with the AUCTeX version?  Anyway, I often prefer doing **C-c C-l** and then **M-PgUp** / **M-PgDn**.

Comment: @mbork Me too. I hardly ever use `C-c \``

Answer (score 1):

It seems it happens when the parser reads a closing bracket when he's not expecting it (it doesn't matter if the bracket is balanced or not). For example, if you get a warning about an overful box containing a `)` (see the link below)

You can try the quickfix given in the link also : compile using

```
latex -file-line-error foo.tex
```

http://old.nabble.com/11.86--TeX-next-error-opens-a-blank-buffer-when-)-appears-in-a-overful-hbox.-td28079618.html